# How to use upsert in kotlin exposed?

Tags: kotlin-exposed

Trying to use `upsert` function added in [exposed 0.42.0](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) but it's giving me below error.

It should run an insert every 5 seconds and an update every 4 secconds after that.

How can i fix?

```
DEBUG Exposed - INSERT INTO counter ("time") VALUES ('21:36:35.564208082') ON CONFLICT ("time") DO UPDATE SET 

WARN  Exposed - Transaction attempt #0 failed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"

INSERT INTO counter ("time") VALUES (?) ON CONFLICT ("time") DO UPDATE SET 

org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
```

```kotlin
object Counter : IdTable<Int>() {
    override val id: Column<EntityID<Int>> = integer("id").autoIncrement().entityId().uniqueIndex()

    val time = time("time")
}


fun roundDownToNearest5Seconds(time: LocalTime): LocalTime {
        val currentSecond = time.second
        val roundedSecond = currentSecond - (currentSecond % 5)
        return time.withSecond(roundedSecond)
    }


fun testUpsert() {
        repeat(10) {
            transaction {
                Counter.upsert(keys= arrayOf(Counter.time)) {
                    it[time] = roundDownToNearest5Seconds(LocalTime.now())
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
```